# Is there any API to get list of multiple users in instagram app or get the userid of currently active user among multiple users?

Tags: ios, instagram, instagram-api, multiple-users

I need to share some content on instagram to specific user, so need to know the active user in app among multiple users.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have usernames with you then -

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search works on usernames. This would return only active users in return.

However, this needs public_content scope which Instagram has stopped issuing. So, if your app is new or sandbox mode - chance are this isn't possible now.